# How to fix "Error: failed to commit transactions, snapd: /snap exists in filesystem, no packages were upgraded."?

Tags: ssl-certificate, archlinux, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

I'm getting problem in upgrading the manjaro packages. How should I fix this?

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
snapd: /snap exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use `snap` package, you should not have `snapd` and `snapd-git` packages installed.

In your case you have `snapd` installed. It maybe installed as a dependency along with another package or whatever reason.

You can simply remove `snapd` package by issuing following command:

```
sudo pacman -R snapd
```

Hope it will help you!